# NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15 instead

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, fabricjs

I am using fabric library for creating a remote connection and copying my files. The code is fine, I have rechecked it several times. But I am getting "NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15 instead" while running the code. I don't even understand the error. For convenience, I am adding the trace of this error.

```
`ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/finalinstallandconn$ python Installation_Manager.py 
connection env is setup
[ubuntu@localhost:22] sudo: mkdir -p /opt/saas/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Installation_Manager.py", line 43, in <module>
    install.install()
  File "Installation_Manager.py", line 34, in install
    self.pre_conditions()
  File "Installation_Manager.py", line 25, in pre_conditions
    self.conn.copy_directory(self.path, "/opt/saas/")
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/finalinstallandconn/connections.py", line 34, in copy_directory
    self.run_remote_command('mkdir -p '+remote_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/finalinstallandconn/connections.py", line 24, in run_remote_command
    sudo(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 649, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/l`enter code here`ib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1109, in sudo
    stderr=stderr, timeout=timeout, shell_escape=shell_escape,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 923, in _run_command
    channel=default_channel(), command=wrapped_command, pty=pty,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/state.py", line 397, in default_channel
    chan = _open_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/state.py", line 389, in _open_session
    return connections[env.host_string].get_transport().open_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 159, in __getitem__
    self.connect(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 151, in connect
    user, host, port, cache=self, seek_gateway=seek_gateway)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 452, in connect
    sock=sock
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 325, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 492, in start_client
    raise e
NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15 instead`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric has some pre-requisits like setuptools,python and paramiko shuld be installed with fabric. Please check your packages.